# How to skip printing (say) the 2nd line of a file?

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have a .csv file where the first two rows contain header information. The second row is in an unfriendly format (punctuation, spaces, etc.), so I'd like to skip printing the second row and pipe the result to another function. How could one do this?

Example file:

```
var1,var2,var3
Variable 1!,Variable 2!,Variable 3!
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Desired output:

```
var1,var2,var3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`, either

```
sed '2d' file
```

(**d**elete line number 2) or

```
sed -n '2!p' file
```

(**p**rint lines not in address range 2; `!` is the negation operator)

With `awk`

```
awk 'NR!=2' file
```

(print if the record number does not equal 2).